supress Java checked Exception
I have writen the following code. I know it might not be the correct approach. but this is what i have done.
public class ValidationRule {
    private static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");
    private static Date afterdt = sdf.parse("1/4/2021");
    private static Date beforedt = sdf.parse("1/4/2025");


in the lines parse function throws "ParseException". I want to know if there is any way to suppress the exception somehow. and make this work.that is my main question.
if you can also suggest any smarter approaches to initiate a date var , i would really appriciate it.
public class ValidationRule {
    private static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");
    private static Date afterdt = sdf.parse("1/4/2021");
    private static Date beforedt = sdf.parse("1/4/2025");
    
    public static Date validateDate(String dts) throws ParseException, DateNotRightException {
        
        Date dt = sdf.parse(dts);
        if(dt.after(afterdt)) {
            throw new DateNotRightException("date too early");
        }
        else if(dt.before(beforedt)) {
            throw new DateNotRightException("date too farrrr");
        }
        
        return dt;
        
    }

this is just a stupid code i am writing to learn concepts.

The Date class is not a good choice for representing calendar dates.  If you use java.time.LocalDate instead, you won’t have to worry about parsing and you won’t have to worry about ambiguity due to timezone issues:  private static LocalDate afterdt = LocalDate.of(2021, 4, 1);

Checked exceptions are used less today than they were 25 years ago. They will not go away completely, but generally modern methods you would use to initialize static fields don’t throw checked exceptions. this is just a stupid code i am writing to learn concepts. More or less outdated concepts, it seems?

As just one example of trouble cause by SimpleDateFormat, Date beforedt = sdf.parse("1/1/2025"); sets beforedt, not to 1 January 2025, but to 30 December 2024. To make matters even worse the result depends on your default locale. You should definitely avoid SimpleDateFormat and related classes. Also for learning concepts like checked exceptions if you ask me.

You could use a static initializer block to initialize your static fields. That way you can have a try-catch to cover your initialization. Like,
private static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");
private static Date afterdt = null;
private static Date beforedt = null;
static {
    try {
        afterdt = sdf.parse("1/4/2021");
        beforedt = sdf.parse("1/4/2025");
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        pe.printStackTrace();
    }
}

